How to assign flag to a group of rows depending on a specific combination of values
I am trying to produce a case statement (if that's the best solution) that can help me capture the following:



ID
Codes
Flag




ID-001
C712
1


ID-001
W943
1


ID-001
W371
1


ID-002
C751
2


ID-002
C712
2


ID-002
W345
2



Whenever a sequence of rows have the value of C712 and C751 together, I want to assign it the value of 2 and whenever the value of C712 shows up without C751 then assign it a value of 1.
I have tried the following case statements but one works whilst the other doesn't
select ID
  ,case sum (case
            when Codes = 'C712' and Codes<> 'C751' then 1 else 0 end) 
            over (partition by ID)
        when 2 then 1 else 0 end

  ,case sum (case
            when ID in('C712','C751') then 1 else 0 end) 
            over (partition by ID)
        when 2 then 2 else 0 end
from table

I'm fairly sure that a window function is needed but I am not sure how to refine it.
Any advice would be appreciated,

when ID in('C712','C751') then 1 else 0 end should be when Codes in('C712','C751') then 1 else 0 end

What value is flag when C712 is not in the group?

Try directly express your text
Whenever a sequence of rows have the value of C712 and C751 together, I want to assign it the value of 2 and whenever the value of C712 shows up without C751 then assign it a value of 1.
See example
select *
  ,case when sum (case when Codes ='C712' then 1 else 0 end)over (partition by ID)>0
    then 
       case when sum (case when Codes ='C751' then 1 else 0 end)over (partition by ID)>0
          then 2
       else 1
       end
   else 0
   end flag
from test

demo

Using CTE
WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT ID, 
         
         CASE 
              --C712 and C751 together, flag =2
              WHEN exists (SELECT 1 FROM example t WHERE t.ID=e.ID AND Codes='C712')  
                   and 
                   exists (SELECT 1 FROM example t WHERE  t.ID=e.ID AND Codes='C751') THEN 2  

              --C712 shows without C751, flag=1
              WHEN exists (SELECT 1 FROM example t WHERE  t.ID=e.ID AND Codes='C712')  
                   and 
                   NOT exists (SELECT 1 FROM example t WHERE  t.ID=e.ID AND Codes ='C751') THEN 1   
              ELSE 0 END as FLAG 
  FROM example e
  GROUP BY ID 
)
SELECT e.ID, e.Codes, c.flag
FROM example e
LEFT JOIN CTE c ON c.id=e.id

fiddle



ID
Codes
Flag




ID-001
C712
1


ID-001
W943
1


ID-001
W371
1


ID-002
C751
2


ID-002
C712
2


ID-002
W345
2



